# how to group records into bucket based on the timestamp?

Tags: shell, timestamp, grouping, logging, bucket

i have a list of entries from the logs:

```
15:38:52.363 1031
15:41:06.347 1259
15:41:06.597 1171
15:48:44.115 1588
15:48:44.125 1366
15:48:44.125 1132
15:53:14.525 1348
15:53:15.121 1553
15:53:15.181 1286
15:53:15.187 1293
```

the first one is the timestamp, the second one is the value.

now i'm trying to group them up by an interval of, say, 20 sec. i want to either sum the values, or get their average. i wonder what's the easiest way to do this? preferrably i can do this thru some simple shell script, so i can pipe my grep statement into and get a divided list. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This `gawk` script completely ignores fractional seconds. It also knows nothing about spanning from one day to the next (crossing 00:00:00):

```
grep ... | awk -v interval=20 'function groupout() {print "----", "Timespan ending:", strftime("%T", prevtime), "Sum:", sum, "Avg:", sum/count, "----"} BEGIN {prevtime = 0} {split($1, a, "[:.]"); time = mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d") " " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3]); if (time > prevtime + interval) {if (NR != 1) {groupout(); sum=0; count=0}}; print; sum+=$2; count++; prevtime = time} END {groupout()}'
```

Output:

```
15:38:52.363 1031
---- Timespan ending: 15:38:52 Sum: 1031 Avg: 1031 ----
15:41:06.347 1259
15:41:06.597 1171
---- Timespan ending: 15:41:06 Sum: 2430 Avg: 1215 ----
15:48:44.115 1588
15:48:44.125 1366
15:48:44.125 1132
---- Timespan ending: 15:48:44 Sum: 4086 Avg: 1362 ----
15:53:14.525 1348
15:53:15.121 1553
15:53:15.181 1286
15:53:15.187 1293
---- Timespan ending: 15:53:15 Sum: 5480 Avg: 1370 ----
```

Here it is again more readably:

```
awk -v interval=20 '
function groupout() {
    print "----", "Timespan ending:", strftime("%T", prevtime), "Sum:", sum, "Avg:", sum/count, "----"
}
BEGIN {
    prevtime = 0
} 
{
    split($1, a, "[:.]"); 
    time = mktime(strftime("%Y %m %d") " " a[1] " " a[2] " " a[3]); 
    if (time > prevtime + interval) {
        if (NR != 1) {groupout(); sum=0; count=0}
    }; 
    print; 
    sum+=$2; 
    count++; 
    prevtime = time
} 
END {groupout()}'
```